# record "new" has no field "user_id" postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

THIS is what i try and error

```
postgres=# INSERT INTO cs222p_interchange.Ad(ad_id, plan, content, pic_num, item_id, seller_user_id, placed_date)
postgres-# VALUES ('ADT32457', 'Gold', 'New games available!', 1, 'F7E1N', '4Z5VC', '2022-11-06');
ERROR:  record "new" has no field "user_id"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO TargetedAds(ad_id, user_id)
SELECT NEW.ad_id, NEW.user_id WHERE (
       SELECT category
       FROM cs222p_interchange.item i
       JOIN cs222p_interchange.ad a ON i.item_id = a.item_id
     WHERE ad_id = NEW.ad_id AND (buyer_user_id = NEW.user_id OR seller_user_id = NEW.user_id) )
LIKE (
       SELECT category
       FROM cs222p_interchange.User u
       JOIN cs222p_interchange.Categories c  ON u.user_id = c.user_id
       WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id)
       ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"
PL/pgSQL function addad() line 1 at SQL statement
```

This is the trigger

```
CREATE FUNCTION AddAd() RETURNS Trigger AS 
$$ 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO TargetedAds(ad_id, user_id) 
SELECT NEW.ad_id, NEW.user_id 
WHERE (
        SELECT * 
        FROM cs222p_interchange.item i 
        JOIN cs222p_interchange.ad a ON i.item_id = a.item_id 
        WHERE ad_id = NEW.ad_id AND (buyer_user_id = NEW.user_id OR seller_user_id = NEW.user_id) )
= (
        SELECT category 
        FROM cs222p_interchange.User u 
        JOIN cs222p_interchange.Categories c  ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
        WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id) 
        ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING; 
RETURN NEW; 
END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL; 

CREATE TRIGGER TargetedAdsLogger AFTER INSERT ON cs222p_interchange.Ad FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION AddAd();
```

This is the Table

```
CREATE TABLE TargetedAds( 
  ad_id text, 
  user_id text, 
  PRIMARY KEY (ad_id, user_id), 
  FOREIGN KEY (ad_id) REFERENCES cs222p_interchange.Ad
(ad_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES cs222p_interchange.Seller(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE 
);
```

This is what i need to insert

```
INSERT INTO cs222p_interchange.Ad(ad_id, plan, content, pic_num, item_id, seller_user_id, placed_date)
VALUES ('ADT32457', 'Gold', 'New games available!', 1, 'F7E1N', '4Z5VC', '2022-11-06');
```

This is the definition of the `Ad` table:

```
CREATE TABLE cs222p_interchange.Ad(
        ad_id        text NOT NULL,
        plan text NOT NULL ,
        content text ,
     pic_num int NOT NULL,
item_id text NOT NULL,
seller_user_id text NOT NULL,
placed_date date NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (ad_id),
FOREIGN KEY(item_id) REFERENCES cs222p_interchange.Item(item_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(pic_num, item_id) REFERENCES cs222p_interchange.Picture(pic_num, item_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(seller_user_id) REFERENCES cs222p_interchange.Seller(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I have checked multiple times and all of my tables and columns are existing.

Comment: Possibly you need to pass a `user_id` to your original insert. Do you  have such column in the `Ad` table?

Comment: "INSERT INTO cs222p_interchange.Ad", that table doesn't have a user_id. The other table has, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Frank Heikens  Ad table have seller_user_id and buyer_user_id, the table User have user_id, but seller and buyer is isa relationship with User

Comment: @GMB Ad table have seller_user_id and buyer_user_id, the table User have user_id, but seller and buyer is isa relationship with User

Comment: 1) The trigger records `NEW` and `OLD` can only access those fields that exist in the table that the trigger is on.  2) You need to show the table definition for `cs222p_interchange.Ad`. 3) If there is a relationship then you need to use the value from the `cs222p_interchange.Ad` side of the relationship in the `SELECT` in the trigger function.

Comment: Again, you don't have a column user_id in the table "Ad". As long as this column doesn't exist, you can't use this non-existing column in a trigger on this table. Use seller_user_id when you need the seller_user_id or so.

Comment: @Frank Heikens
how should i edit it?

Comment: Can't help you there, I don't know what the code should do. My gut feeling tells me there must be a better way than this too complex piece of code.